# how to rewrite in a htacess file

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

im into SEO and friendly URL's and im trying to create a rule in my htacess file and i need help...

Basically, i have a list of alphabet letters. If the users selects one letter, the db will show all the lyrics that starts with that letter...

so if i click C, there will be a list of lyrics and the the first is 'Car and blues'

So, from this

```
htpp://www.website.com/lyrics.php?letter=C
```

i want to do this:

```
http://www.website.com/lyrics/C/
```

so far, this is what i have

```
RewriteRule ^lyrics/$ /lyrics.php?letter=$1 [L]
```

the rule should be smart enough to pick everything that comes after 'lyrics', in between the 2 slashes, and not what comes after...

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`the rule should be smart enough to pick everything that comes after 'lyrics', in between the 2 slashes, and not what comes after...`

Your rule as it stands is looking for exactly `lyrics/` with no possibility of anything before or after it (as defined by the `^` and `$`).

Assuming you're using letters A-Z in only capitals, you can use this:

```
RewriteRule ^lyrics/([A-Z])/?$ /lyrics.php?letter=$1 [L]
```

This will look for a single capital letter after the `lyrics/` and send that value to the rewrite URL and also match both cases of having a trailing `/` or not.

Answer (score 0):

> the rule should be smart enough to pick everything that comes after
>   'lyrics', in between the 2 slashes, and not what comes after...

I'd suggest you look into using regular expressions to format your url. See [this link](http://expressionengine.com/wiki/Regular_Expressions_in_.htaccess)